# Keeping track of users with PHP session id, cookie + database

Tags: php, session

I'm having a small bit of doubts here as to how sessions should be handled.

Right now, I have a MySQL database where the "users" table has a field for session_id. If NULL, the user is not logged in? If the value is the same as the value of the PHPSESSID cookie, than the user is logged in.

I don't know why, but I somehow feel this isn't good enough a way to make sure which user I'm dealing with. Is there something I'm missing, or do my fears hold no ground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing essentially wrong with what you describe as far as I can see.

Of course, your login and logout mechanisms need to reliably add and remove the user ID when logging in or out. (insert a user name only when passwords match, etc) . Also, expired sessions need to be removed reliably. If that is given, this should be fine.

Comment: Yeah, the logout includes destroying the session cookie and setting the session field to NULL, plus the destroying of the server side session.

Answer (score 2):

Just an extension on what Pekka said, you could also include a 'last seen' field into your table and use that as a judge because as Pekka mentioned about expired sessions, your database won't be informed that they are gone.  So you will be forced to either make something so it manually checks the last time a user was there or something along those lines and then map that back to the session timeout (which I believe is either 15-30 minutes by default for PHP) and then after said amount of time, clear any of the users who haven't been active within the last X minutes.

Answer (score 2):

A thought of the options above - tracking a user in the user table would only allow 1 session per user. I suggest storing the data in a table called sessions and have these columns:

sess_id | sess_userid | sess_ipv4 | sess_lastseen(datetime/timestamp) | sess_sessionid (varchar)

I believe that will allow user to have multiple logins, but with different session id's, even if they share the same public IP, allowing a laptop, tablet, phone etc - this way u can track each device separately from a single user.

hope this helps!

Another post ir read last week suggested having a prevsession and currsession and making sure u are assigning a new session (every 15 mins?) to the correct user. . swapping the sessions from old to new and storing the prev session as a check - not sure if this would help but thought id mention it.